# Upload tracks using SoundCloud API on iOS

Tags: ios, audio, file-upload, httprequest, soundcloud

I have to upload a mp3 file to SoundCloud, using a HTTP method. I receive no errors, but the file does not appear uploaded on SoundCloud.

I'm using a `multipart/form-data request`

This is how I'm currently proceeding:(I have already done connection, authorization and I know my user ID).

```
NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=%@&user_id=%@&title=%@&tag_list=%@&sharing=%@&oauth_token=%@",SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_ID, inputData[@"user_id"],inputData[@"title"],inputData[@"tag_list”],inputData[@"sharing”], ACCESS_TOKEN];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
request.HTTPMethod = @“POST”;

NSString *boundary= @“SoundCloud”;
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n--%@\n",boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\”asset_data\"; filename=\"%@\"\n”,@“my file name.mp3"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: audio/mpeg\n\n” dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *audioData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"untitled" ofType:@"mp3”]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:audioData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n--%@", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

request.HTTPBody = body;

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lud",(unsigned long)[body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length”];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@,boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-Type"];
request.timeoutInterval = 30;
self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[self.connection start];
```

The `.mp3` file is actually where I search, so that "audioData" has the right content.
I receive a 200 HTTP response code:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse:{ URL: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=[...]&user_id=[...]&title=dgd&tag_list=wgn&sharing=public&oauth_token=[...] } { status code: 200, headers {

"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin";
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE";
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Access-Control-Expose-Headers" = Date;
"Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Mon, 08 Dec 2014 15:58:57 GMT";
Etag = "\"66cc86baea454001c9572594b9caeea0\"";
Server = "am/2";
"Set-Cookie" = "_session_auth_key=\"LdrvaLfDKfaGihR714EaihOotlo=\"";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} }
```

Then, the response json is an array containing the list of all the tracks on my account. No error, but no file is uploaded. The same kind of response is obtained by simulator and device.
Any suggestions are welcome.

P.S. I also tried the post request changing the body and the content-type like this, but with no working result:

```
NSDictionary *body=@{@"asset_data":[[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"untitled" ofType:@"mp3"]]base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]};
NSData *bodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:body options:0 error:&error];
request.HTTPBody = bodyData;
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-Type"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar and I'm getting code 400, but I've also included an access token, which I think you need.

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_token\"\r\n\r\n%@", self.scToken] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

I now have working code for uploading a song with NSURLRequest. I hope this helps you.

```
-(void)uploadTrackTitled:(NSString*)title withPath:(NSString*)trackPath {
    NSURLSession* urlSession = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLRequest* urlRequest = [self getURLRequest:title withAudioPath:trackPath];

    NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = [urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        NSLog(@"returned: %ld", (long)httpResponse.statusCode);

        if(data) {
            NSString* stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"%@", stringResponse);
        }

        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
}

-(NSURLRequest*)getURLRequest:(NSString*)title withAudioPath:(NSString*)audioPath {
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    NSString* boundary = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
    CFRelease(uuid);
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[self getPostData:self.scToken withBoundary:boundary andTitle:title withAudioPath:audioPath]];

    NSString* contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];

    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    return request;
}

-(NSData*)getPostData:(NSString*)token withBoundary:(NSString*)boundary andTitle:(NSString*)title withAudioPath:(NSString*)audioPath {
    NSString* boundaryStart = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary];
    NSString* boundaryEnd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary];
    NSMutableData* bodyData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    //add the token
    NSMutableString* tokenSection = [NSMutableString stringWithString:boundaryStart];
    [tokenSection appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_token\"\r\n\r\n"];
    [tokenSection appendFormat:@"%@\r\n", token];
    [bodyData appendData:[tokenSection dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //track title
    NSMutableString* titleSection = [NSMutableString stringWithString:boundaryStart];
    [titleSection appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"track[title]\"\r\n\r\n"];
    [titleSection appendFormat:@"%@\r\n", title];
    [bodyData appendData:[titleSection dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //add the audio file
    NSData* trackData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:audioPath];
    NSMutableString* trackSection = [NSMutableString stringWithString:boundaryStart];
    [trackSection appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"track[asset_data]\"; "];
    [trackSection appendFormat:@"filename=\"%@\"\r\n", [audioPath lastPathComponent]];
    [trackSection appendFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"];

    [bodyData appendData:[trackSection dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:trackData];

    //ending
    [bodyData appendData:[boundaryEnd dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    return bodyData;
}
```